# Getting the attributes of each form element using php xpath but results are incorrect

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath, field

I'm trying to get each nodes value using DomXPath() but the results are incorrect. If you take a look at the results , not all the fields attributes are showing up and are sometimes showing up incorrect. I figure the query is incorrect but i don't know how else to do it. I need the labels value, an inputs type, field name and value. Would there be another way to do this?

```
<?php
    $request = "http://dev.app/dropdown/table.html";
    $content = file_get_contents($request);
    $content = preg_replace("/&(?!(?:apos|quot|[gl]t|amp);|#)/", '&amp;', $content);

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($content);
    $xpath = new DomXPath($doc);

    $data = $xpath->query('//form//label | //form//input | //form//select');

    echo '<pre>';
    foreach($data as $item)
    {
        echo 'Label: <strong>' . $item->nodeValue . '</strong><br/>';
        echo 'Field TagName: <strong>' . $item->tagName . '</strong><br/>';
        echo 'Field Name: <strong>' . $item->getAttribute('name') . '</strong><br/>';
        echo 'Field Type: <strong>' . $item->getAttribute('type') . '</strong><br/>';
        echo 'Field Value: <strong>' . $item->getAttribute('value') . '</strong><br/>';
        echo '<br/><br/>';
    }
```

and here are the results

```
Label: First Name: 
Field TagName: label
Field Name: 
Field Type: 
Field Value: 


Label: 
Field TagName: input
Field Name: fname
Field Type: text
Field Value: 


Label: Last Name: 
Field TagName: label
Field Name: 
Field Type: 
Field Value: 


Label: 
Field TagName: input
Field Name: lname
Field Type: text
Field Value: 


Label: Address: 
Field TagName: label
Field Name: 
Field Type: 
Field Value: 


Label: 
Field TagName: input
Field Name: address
Field Type: text
Field Value: 


Label: Address2: 
Field TagName: label
Field Name: 
Field Type: 
Field Value: 


Label: 
Field TagName: input
Field Name: address2
Field Type: text
Field Value: 


Label: City: 
Field TagName: label
Field Name: 
Field Type: 
Field Value: 


Label: 
Field TagName: input
Field Name: city
Field Type: text
Field Value: 


Label: State: 
Field TagName: label
Field Name: 
Field Type: 
Field Value: 


Label: 
Field TagName: input
Field Name: state
Field Type: text
Field Value: 


Label: Zipcode: 
Field TagName: label
Field Name: 
Field Type: 
Field Value: 


Label: 
Field TagName: input
Field Name: zipcode
Field Type: text
Field Value: 


Label: Country: 
Field TagName: label
Field Name: 
Field Type: 
Field Value: 


Label: 
Field TagName: input
Field Name: country
Field Type: text
Field Value:
```

and here is the html page (table.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="">
    <div>
        <label for="fname">First Name: </label>
        <input type="text" name="fname">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="lname">Last Name: </label>
        <input type="text" name="lname">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="address">Address: </label>
        <input type="text" name="address">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="address2">Address2: </label>
        <input type="text" name="address2">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="city">City: </label>
        <input type="text" name="city">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="state">State: </label>
        <input type="text" name="state">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="zipcode">Zipcode: </label>
        <input type="text" name="zipcode">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="country">Country: </label>
        <input type="text" name="country">
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "label value"? A label hasn't a "value" attribute. "nodeValue" is its `inner html`. The query seems to be correct.

Comment: if the query is correct then why arent all the label nodeValues being pulled? All of them in the html below have label nodevalues.

Comment: What is it that is not working? For `label` elements you get the node value (e.g. `Address: `) in your output and for `input` elements your get the `name` (e.g. `fname`) and `type` (e.g. `text`) attributes correctly. You get no input `value` because there is no such attribute value present in the HTML. What would be your expected output?

Comment: Please reduce your example to the minimum code needed to demonstrate the issue. That should be a single form and one label and one input element. Also demonstration output should be written as text not HTML as the requirement is to make the example as small as possible with as little code / data *as necessary* to demonstrate the issue. This should also make more clear what your concrete question is (see as well the other latest comment).